# How to add <a> link to svg path to navigate to another svg image using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I am new to svg. I have two svg images i need to append  link around the path in one svg image, onclicking that path i should navigate to another svg image.

```
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <g id="path1">
     <a xlink:href="" target="_top">
       <path id="parcel" />
     </a>
     </g>
 </svg>
```

How should i get  attribute into my application(html) and append href link to it using javascript. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Get a reference to the `<a>` element using whichever method you choose.  For example

```
 <a id="mylink" xlink:href="" target="_top">
   <path id="parcel" />
 </a>

var  mylink = document.getElementById("mylink");
```

Then you can set the `xlink:href` attribute using:

```
mylink.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href',
                      'http://www.google.com');
```